# How do I upgrade a hero's star rating?

Tags: injustice-2-mobile

I have a few heroes now and I'm trying to level up their star rating but I can't figure out how to do it.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To level up the star ranking of your heroes you must obtain enough hero shards for the specific hero you are trying to upgrade. There are numerous ways to obtain these shards but once you obtain enough to upgrade your hero you can click on your hero and hit promote. Do note you do need a small sum of credits to perform the upgrade but it isn't anything too expensive.